# Problem to debug stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

There is a SP which gets over 96 items as parameters.
I want to debug this sp, how can I do it?

It says:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0."
>   System.Data.Common.DbException {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Please tell me a way to find this error? I will give more details the more answers come..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the number of parameters... start going through the code and counting the BEGIN entries as a +1 and COMMIT entries as a -1.. when you get to a place where your count is a -1, you found the error.  Or, if you get to the end and your count isn't 0, there's your error.  Every begin must have one commit.

Answer (score 3):

This SP will run properly:

```
BEGIN TRAN
...
COMMIT
```

---

But this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
...
```

or this:

```
...
COMMIT
```

will not!